# Questions Around Recommendations For Hosting etc

Tags: serverfault, sf

There have been a number of questions from users asking for recommendations for:

- cheap web hosting
- VPS hosting
- servers
- more, etc.

We know that a sister community, [SuperUser is being developed](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/) to handle all those questions relating to anything non StackOverflow and ServerFault is being developed.

Do these types of questions belong on ServerFault or SuperUser? Should they be closed or moved to SuperUser? There is a gray area here where Small-Medium Business sysadmins need to know where to host their pop3/www services. These may well be valid sysadmin questions.

Please vote for the option you prefer below.

Answer (score 13):

### YES

I do want to see recommendations for particular paid for services on SF

Comment: These are sometimes very useful from an administrators point of view, but usually only from the personal server administration, rather than the work server administration. Still valid, IMO, but should be community wiki rather than reputation earning questions, since it's essentially a poll.

Comment: Slicehost was recommended to me and I use it at work - we don't necessarily want everything hosted in-house.

Comment: Agree with Kyle's comment on the NO side .. I like discussions around criteria and considerations and don't want to see bunches of "xyz is great!" nonsense.

Answer (score 5):

### NO

I do not want to see recommendations for particular paid for services on SF

Comment: I think these are not so productive and will lead to lots of 'noise'.  However, rephrased 'What to consider when choosing a VPS provider' might lead to more productive results.

Comment: The selection of a host is primarily a business decision, although it should go without saying that IT should have serious input into that decision. I see hosting as little more an IT matter than choosing a car to drive to and from work. OTOH, I agree with Kyle's comment.

Comment: Instead of having people to ask about it, make a nice FAQ with list of known and most used hosts that will serve in general by everyone and has a majority votes (by majority votes i mean the hosts that have most recommendations instead of spamming unknown and any kinda of host company) by the head users of SF Meta. Divided in sections such as VPS, CLOUD, HOSTING, DEDICATED, CO-LOCATION, etc.